# looping over lazyDataModel

Tags: java, primefaces

I use lazyDataModel in my prime faces project to view some data in lazy behavior through prime faces datable, however this works fine. My problem is that I cannot loop or iterate over this lazyDataModel in my bean, it doesn't return any error but it acts like it is empty list, so how i can loop over my lazyDataModel. Here is my code below :

```
LazyDataModel<Supplier> supplierList = SupplierService.getAllSuppliers();
for (Supplier existingSupplier : supplierList) {
                if (existingSupplier.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(supplierName) && existingSupplier.getPhone().equalsIgnoreCase(phone)) {
                    supplierExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tried if there are any method calls (aka api) on the supplierList  that DO return something?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot loop a LazyDataModel object this way.

You can get the list of objects it contains using the load() method that should have been overwritten when you created the LazyDataModel object.

You should have some code like this, when creating it:

```
    supplierDataModel = new LazyDataModel<Teren>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<Supplier> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
            return (List<Supplier>) getSupplierListMethod(whatever arguments);
    };
```

Then, to access the objects in it, you can call the previously mentioned **load** method with the parameters that suit you.